# Tree recursion compiles, but crashes on execution

Tags: c, function, recursion, tree, nodes

I'm writing a program to traverse a pre-built tree. I don't know anything about the tree structure as far as number of nodes, location of nodes, etc, but I need to traverse all the nodes and sum the values of the nodes.

The node is defined as

```
struct node
{
  int value;
  node* left;
  node* right;
}
```

And my recursive function is the following:

```
int sumTheTreeValues(struct node* root)
{
  int sum = root->value;
    if(!root->left){
    sum = sum + sumTheTreeValues(root->left);
  }
    else if(!root->right){
      sum = sum + sumTheTreeValues(root->right);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

The compiler throws no error, but if I try to run it it just crashes with no messages. Just to sanity check I printed the node value to make sure the root is not `null`. I have a hunch that it might be related to recursion termination, but I'm not quite sure what else to add since I am checking for `null` children.

Comment: `if(!root->left){` means if it is a `NULL` pointer, so you are only calling the function with `NULL` pointer and dereference it at the begin.

Comment: @mch oh, yeap! That fixed it. Confused myself there. Thanks!

Comment: The `else` would seem counterproductive if your task is to visit all nodes.

Comment: I much prefer `if (root->left == NULL)` and `if (root->left != NULL)` because people don't make mistakes when written out in full.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yea, i tried to get fancy instead of keeping it simple and readable. Lessons learned! That being said, if you look at my comments for Vlad's answer, for some reason equating `root` to `null` or `NULL` didnt compile, so im not sure what else i would do or why it happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the structure in C has to be declared like

```
struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
```

The condition in this if statement

```
if(!root->left){
```

is equivalent to

```
if( root->left == NULL ){
```

So the function is recursively called for the left and right nodes when they are equal to NULL. However inside the function there is no check that `root` is equal to `NULL`. So the function has undefined behavior.

Also it does not make sense to enclose the calls of the function for the left and the right nodes in the if-else statement.

The function can be defined the following way

```
long long int sumTheTreeValues( struct node *root )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    if ( root )
    {
        sum = root->value + 
              sumTheTreeValues( root->left ) + 
              sumTheTreeValues( root->right );
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Or like

```
long long int sumTheTreeValues( struct node *root )
{
    return root == NULL ? 0
                        : root->value + sumTheTreeValues( root->left ) 
                                      + sumTheTreeValues( root->right );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program with two recursive functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

void insert( struct node **head, int value )
{
    if ( *head == NULL )
    {
        *head = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        ( *head )->value = value;
        ( *head )->left = NULL;
        ( *head )->right = NULL;
    }
    else if ( value < ( *head )->value )
    {
        insert( &( *head )->left, value );
    }
    else
    {
        insert( &( *head )->right, value );
    }
}

long long int sumTheTreeValues( struct node *root )
{
    return root == NULL ? 0
                        : root->value + sumTheTreeValues( root->left ) 
                                      + sumTheTreeValues( root->right );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        insert( &head, i );
    }

    printf( "%lld\n", sumTheTreeValues( head ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
45
```

Comment: I just tried it and it crashed, but it did compile.

Comment: @dorojevets The reason can be that the nodes are incorrectly added to the tree or the tree is too big.

Comment: I tried the second version and got this: "error: use of undeclared identifier "NULL" `return root == NULL ? 0`". I also tried `null` but still didnt work. Am i missing something??

Comment: Changing it from `root == NULL` to `!root` worked. Not sure why `NULL` or `null` didnt compile though.

Comment: @dorojevets: If you run into problems with NULL not being defined, it means you didn't include a header that defined NULL.  The standard headers that do define it are `<stddef.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<time.h>` and `<wchar.h>` — it might also be defined by a few others.  Any one of those will do, but `<stddef.h>` is the smallest.